# Visual Studio Code doesn't show indent until I highlight the text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a number of files in different languages with indent (tabs) in them. When I open the files the indent are not shown by default and the lines appear against the left border of the editor. As soon as I select the text, the indent re-appear.

Comment: How long has this been happening? Does this still happen after closing VS and reopening?

Comment: From since I started using it months ago. Yes, it always happen.